# HHVM Not Using memcached as Save Handler?

Tags: php, memcached, hhvm

I'm using HHVM to serve up my PHP content, and have a `memcached` instance setup with a view to using it as a save handler for sessions, however I'm not sure that HHVM is actually using it.

Here's the relevant part of `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = /tmp/memcached.sock
memcached.sess_prefix = 'php_'
```

Note; I had to use a `session.save_handler` value of `memcached` rather than `memcache` as used in vanilla PHP. I also had to set a `memcached.sess_prefix` otherwise I was getting errors about it being empty.

However, if I connect to `memcached` and request its statistics, it doesn't look as if any sessions are being stored in `memcached` at all.

Here are the stats for hits/misses:

```
STAT get_hits 15
STAT get_misses 29
```

The `memcached` daemon has been running for several weeks uninterrupted, so these values seem extremely low. In fact I suspect they were probably generated when I briefly used a vanilla PHP installation before switching to `hhvm`.

There are no errors in `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` pertaining to memcached, or sessions, so it doesn't appear to be failing to connect, which suggests that it simply isn't trying. Though if that's the case I have no idea how sessions are being stored as they don't seem to be going into `/tmp`, but they do appear to work (does HHVM/PHP store any session data in RAM itself?)

Everything seems like it's configured correctly, is there something else that I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that HHVM simply does not support `memcached`, even though setting the save handler to "memcached" results in no errors or warning messages (whereas `memcache` is reported as unrecognised).

This is unfortunate, but I found HHVM's stability to be poor when unable to precompile all of my scripts, so I've switched to PHP 7 instead anyway. PHP 7 doesn't have `memcached` support yet either, but it will hopefully be restored soon.

Comment: What is your reference showing that HHVM does not support memcached? etsy is using hhvm with memcached (noting issues with memcached) https://codeascraft.com/2015/04/06/experimenting-with-hhvm-at-etsy/

Comment: From that article it sounds like Etsy had to compile their own memcache extension for HHVM due to numerous issues; at the time I posted my answer the issues with memcache still don't appear to be fixed, even though memcache gives the appearance of being supported in HHVM, it wasn't reliable at all.

Comment: I'll have to look at this again when HHVM 3.14 or 3.15 comes out. 3.13 is busted for compiling your own extensions